# EEPlus excel error only in T.TEST formula

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following code:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = Strain.OfficialName;
worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = data.Average;
worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = data.StandardError;
worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Formula = "T.TEST({" + string.Join(",", controlData) + "},{" + string.Join(",", data.Values) + "},2,3)";
```

`controlData` and `data.Values` are both `double[]`.
The excel file is beeing written, first three values work fine.
The 4th cell on the other hand shows `#NAME?` error in excel. When I check the formula in the excel file, it looks fine. for example: `=T.TEST({98.1578163604527,91.0169216716966,57.6033090316311,153.22195293622},{98.1578163604527,91.0169216716966,57.6033090316311,153.22195293622},2,3)`
When I click on the check mark next to the formula it suddenly works and gives a proper value.
I tried adding this after inserting the formula:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Calculate();
```

Didn't work.
I then tried another function:

```
    worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Formula = "SUM(" + string.Join(",", data.Values) + ")";
    worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Formula = "SUM({" + string.Join(",", data.Values) + "})";
```

Both cells worked fine. What is so special about the T.TEST function? why am I getting this error?